# How to turn off second hard drive while working with the first?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, battery-life

I have 2 hard drives , SSD and mechanical in my laptop .most of the software and OS are in the SSD . how to turn off the mechanical hard drive to save battery life when working with the SSD ?

Comment: Are you using Windows, what version ? If so, there's options in the control panel > power management where you can set the time until the hard drive spins down when inactive.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm using Windows 10 I want to turn the mechanical drive off while working on SSD